# Camera Remote API for HDR-AS50

Tags: camera, sony

I used to control my HDR-AZ1 via the camera remote api via IP and port 192.168.122.1:8080. With my new HDR-AS50, while it listens to the same IP address, port 8080 does not work (connection refused). Is there a differnt port used for this model? 
Can somebody provide the camera remote api documentation for the HDR-AS50?

Comment: Found the correct ports by getting http://192.168.122.1:64321/dd.xml

Comment: Any news about camera remote api docs for the AS50?

Answer (score 0):

The HDR-AS50 is not supported in the Camera Remote API at this time.  Please stay tuned to the Sony Developer page for news about SDK updates (http://www.sony.com/developer).